# Game World structure in classes

Tags: java, class

I am developing a 2D game in Java and I want some basic ingame scripting (spawn enemy, spawn item, changing enemies properties).

What I don't know is how to divide the game world so I can easily work with it.

I need enemies (with health and basic AI) of different types, item classes (can be picked by player), tile map with different blocks.

How can I organize my game world architecture? and What basic classes should I use to easily extend and maintain Game World?

Comment: This question is more suited to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Elaborate more about your game. Do enemies attack? Does everything have health, or are there only one hit kills? Do you collect items by running over them? Talk a lot more about how everything works, and it'll be easier to design the class architecture.

Comment: Come on people, how is it “difficult to tell what is being asked here”?

Comment: Please don't ask both here and on gamedev SE at about the same time. It's rude and a waste of peoples' time.

Comment: I am sorry, second time i dont do  that, and thank you for your edit on gamedev,

Answer (score 3):

game world basics to me are about finding common grounds.

the world going forward in time. so are all active elements (player, dropped items, enemies, npc's) but all passive elements are not (block of stone, tree, house) therefor i'd use 2 interfaces ActiveElement and PassiveElement. the active element could have a stepintime() function which is called by the game world each time itself steps in time. both elements could have a render() function which draws the element whenever the gameworld is drawn on a canvas.

then all enemies should call their ai to determine their next step in time as well as checking collision with any other objects and whatever that means (trees bullets players etc) same goes basically for every other element.

this is to me the most basic architecture in gameworlds.

then there's the issue of performance where it might be better to put certain things in their own threads and let them run (enemy ai that is checking the position and status of his avatar each cycle and makes input which is read with each step in time) but there i dont have enough experience in to elaborate. then you should go to a gamedev site (eg as karim79 said).

implemented elements can have their own attributes then and is easy to expand(health, stats)
and write an interpreter that reads simpel scripts that communicates with the gameworld adding enemies etc.

ciao

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a layout similar to [this](http://www.theadamgaskins.com/upload/318_Untitaled.png).

`GameObject` has functions such as `Draw()` and `Move()`. Then `Enemy` sets up some more functions and variables for implementing Artificial Intelligence in `Goblin` and `Unicorn`. `Player` contains all the stuff for moving the player in `Move()`.

Thats just a general idea of what I would do. Its different for every game, depending on what type of game it is and how you play it.